# NSMutableArray in NSUserDefault, retrieve NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

In my class first controller i have:

```
UITextField * title = textfields [0];
NSString *html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                  @"document.body.innerHTML"];

InfoHtml * newFeed = [[InfoHtml alloc] init];
NewFeed.title = title.text;
NewFeed.html = html;
                           
[self.arrayHTML addObject: newFeed];
                
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];[UserDefaults setObject: self.arrayHTML forKey: @ "test"];
[UserDefaults synchronize];
```

where arrayHTML is a NSMutableArray and InfoHtml is a class model:

```
@interface InfoHtml : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *html;
@end
```

In my other controlller, i try to retrieve this array with:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.arrayHTML = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayHTML);
```

> NSLog prints: (null)

Why?

Comment: What is `UserDefaults`? Do you mean `userDefaults`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you alloc self.arrayHTML anywhere? Can't see it on your code, so maybe you need to alloc it before adding objects.

```
self.arrayHTML = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

or

```
self.arrayHTML = [NSMutableArray new];
```

After all it was a lifecycle problem overlapping self.arrayHTML

Comment: yep, i have this in didLoad: `(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arrayHTML = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.arrayHTML = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"test"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
     NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayHTML);
}`

Comment: Can you check how it looks after this line: [self.arrayHTML addObject: newFeed];

Can you NSLog that?

Comment: What do you want to print?? `NSLog("%@, self.arrayHTML");` ?

Comment: Yes, right after adding a new object, print the array. 

 [self.arrayHTML addObject: newFeed]
NSLog("%@, self.arrayHTML");

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "<InfoHtml: 0x608000438fc0>"
) for key test'

Comment: So that means you self.arrayHTML is empty when you try to insert in key Test, but it shouldn't... Did you inserted the NSlog like this?

`InfoHtml * newFeed = [[InfoHtml alloc] init];
NewFeed.title = title.text;
NewFeed.html = html;
                           
[self.arrayHTML addObject: newFeed];
NSLog("%@, self.arrayHTML");
`

Comment: Ok sorry, now NSLog says: `"<InfoHtml: 0x60800042d8e0>"` Is memory location?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149532/discussion-between-ppinho-and-taprolano).

Comment: The line `self.arrayHTML = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"test"];` sets `self.arrayHTML` to `nil` because there is no such value in user defaults yet.

Answer (score 0):

Frist , make sure that U have already performed NSCoding delegate in InfoHtml class , and implement `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder` `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`methods